# Run Scrapy Web Crawler with Selenium in Linux Server

Tags: python, linux, selenium, scrapy, web-crawler

I developed a web crawler by scrapy and selenium(python). and it can run successfully on my local. I am curiosity could i upload my whole crawler project into my linux server, and run it like on the local???

Only one concern is on my local, when the program ran, it will open the browser and imitate the action like human being, but in the linux server, like you know, there is no browser we can open.

So Could we do that???

Answer (score 2):

You can use a virtual display to run a headless X-server.

Install first the packages if are not already:

```
sudo apt-get install xvfb python-pip
sudo pip install pyvirtualdisplay
```

And add the following code before starting a Selenium webdriver:

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()
```

Then close the driver at the end of the execution:

```
display.stop()
```

Comment: thanks for reply
I try this way, and it seems work fine at the starting(like preparing, since it output the info of my spider). but it will get stuck on the first post forever. 

Could u give me any suggestions?

Comment: I don't quite understand the problem, where does it get stuck? Please, edit your post with your code so I can follow it and try to identify the problem.

Comment: https://github.com/HUAZHEYINy/ErrorTest/blob/master/README.md
I copy what i got from console window into the link. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I meant your actual code, I can't tell only for the error trace why does it get stuck. You can just edit your post to add it, I'll try to do my best.

Comment: https://github.com/HUAZHEYINy/ErrorTest/blob/master/spider.py
sorry for replying late, here is the source code.